# Ruby and SLIP (Serial Line Internet Protocol)

Tags: ruby, windows, tcp, serial-port

Is there any Ruby gem which can deal with the SLIP protocol? I could not find one.

If there is none, I wonder if there is a C library that I can use in order to make one such gem. (similar to serialport.gem which uses the same approach from what I recall)

All I need to do is read and interpret what is received on the serial line, I don't need to send anything.

My OS is Windows.

Comment: I doubt it, though there are plenty of TCP wrappers...